# How to enlarge data column in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to check my source code with cppcheck and SonarQube.

When I run sonar-runner, I met error below

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.6.0_33 Sun Microsystems Inc. (64-bit)
Linux 3.11.0-26-generic amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/sonarqube/sonar-runner-2.4/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MIP35.KT.Centrex.Branch/workspace/hudson_mvmw/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "ko_KR", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /data/jenkins/jobs/MIP35.KT.Centrex.Branch/workspace/hudson_mvmw/./.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5
16:23:56.070 INFO  - Load global referentials...
16:23:56.152 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 84 ms
16:23:56.158 INFO  - User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
16:23:56.164 INFO  - Install plugins
16:23:56.273 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
16:23:56.278 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
16:23:57.156 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
16:23:57.990 INFO  - Load project referentials...
16:23:58.522 INFO  - Load project referentials done: 532 ms
16:23:58.522 INFO  - Load project settings
16:23:58.788 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
16:23:58.809 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 21 ms
16:23:58.811 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
16:23:58.962 INFO  - -------------  Scan mvmw for KT centrex at branch
16:23:58.968 INFO  - Load module settings
16:23:59.939 INFO  - Language is forced to c++
16:23:59.940 INFO  - Loading rules...
16:24:00.558 INFO  - Loading rules done: 618 ms
16:24:00.576 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
16:24:00.660 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
16:24:00.759 INFO  - Base dir: /data/jenkins/jobs/MIP35.KT.Centrex.Branch/workspace/hudson_mvmw/.
16:24:00.759 INFO  - Working dir: /data/jenkins/jobs/MIP35.KT.Centrex.Branch/workspace/hudson_mvmw/./.sonar
16:24:00.760 INFO  - Source paths: moimstone
16:24:00.760 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: ko_KR
16:24:00.760 INFO  - Index files
16:24:20.825 INFO  - 13185 files indexed
16:26:35.895 WARN  - SQL Error: 1406, SQLState: 22001
16:26:35.895 ERROR - Data truncation: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2:40.236s
Final Memory: 27M/1765M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to read and import the source file : '/data/jenkins/jobs/MIP35.KT.Centrex.Branch/workspace/hudson_mvmw/moimstone/mgrs/mUIMgr/gui/resource/wideBasicStyle/320Wx240H/imageMerged.c' with the charset : 'UTF-8'.
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.ComponentIndexer.importSources(ComponentIndexer.java:96)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.ComponentIndexer.execute(ComponentIndexer.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.DefaultModuleFileSystem.index(DefaultModuleFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:111)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to persist : SnapshotSource[snapshot_id=53035,data=#if defined(__cplusplus)
#pragma hdrstop
#endif

#include "Prj_pcx2_resource.h"

#if defined(__cplusplus)
#pragma package(smart_init)
#endif

const rgb24_type Prj_Bg_call_ColorTable[59] PCX2_SEGMENT = 
{
    {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF}, {0xFE,0xFE,0xFE}, {0xE7,0xE7,0xE7}, {0xC7,0xC7,0xC7}, {0x9B,0x9B,0x9B}, {0xFD,0xFD,0xFD}, {0xCF,0xCF,0xCF}, {0xA8,0xA8,0xA8}, {0xBC,0xBC,0xBC}, {0xD6,0xD6,0xD6}, 
    {0xDC,0xDC,0xDC}, {0xCE,0xCE,0xCE}, {0xB5,0xB5,0xB5}, {0xD0,0xD0,0xD0}, {0xE1,0xE1,0xE1}, {0xA7,0xA7,0xA7}, {0xFA,0xFA,0xFA}, {0xBE,0xBE,0xBE}, {0xBB,0xBB,0xBB}, {0xF3,0xF3,0xF3}, 
    {0x9A,0x9A,0x9A}, {0xEC,0xEC,0xEC}, {0xE9,0xE9,0xE9}, {0x99,0x99,0x99}, {0x98,0x98,0x98}, {0x97,0x97,0x97}, {0x96,0x96,0x96}, {0x95,0x95,0x95}, {0x94,0x94,0x94}, {0x93,0x93,0x93}, 
    {0x92,0x92,0x92}, {0x91,0x91,0x91}, {0x90,0x90,0x90}, {0x8F,0x8F,0x8F}, {0x8E,0x8E,0x8E}, {0x8D,0x8D,0x8D}, {0x8C,0x8C,0x8C}, {0x8B,0x8B,0x8B}, {0x8A,0x8A,0x8A}, {0x89,0x89,0x89}, 
    {0x88,0x88,0x88}, {0x87,0x87,0x87...]
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.internalSave(JpaDatabaseSession.java:136)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.save(JpaDatabaseSession.java:103)
    at org.sonar.batch.index.SourcePersister.saveSource(SourcePersister.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultPersistenceManager.setSource(DefaultPersistenceManager.java:68)
    at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.setSource(DefaultIndex.java:467)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.ComponentIndexer.importSources(ComponentIndexer.java:93)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [org.sonar.api.database.model.SnapshotSource]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:226)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.internalSave(JpaDatabaseSession.java:130)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [org.sonar.api.database.model.SnapshotSource]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2176)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2656)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:624)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:220)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4235)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2459)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2360)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 55 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I have a huge source file which is image data file. It's over 100 Megabytes.

How can I enlarge data column? Is there setting for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in analyzing such a file, SonarQube won't give you useful information about it. And this is true for any other file like this one.

The solution is to exclude those image data files using the [standard exclusion mechanism](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles) provided by SonarQube.
For instance, I would do something like:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*imageMerged*
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. That file is just a bmp image data. So it's not important. I didn't know that there is such a exclusion option. Thank very much.